# Dynamic remarketing without feed in Google Merchant Center

Tags: google-ads-api

Is it possible to use dynamic remarketing in Adwords, without have to import every product into Google Merchant Center?

I am using Tag Manager, wouldn't it be great if I just could use the dataLayer to push information about the products I want to use remarketing on. For example when a user hit the "product view info page".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make remarketing lists with [custom parameters in URL](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/3111920#standard_parameters), but for dynamic remarketing in AdWords, you need to upload / import feed into Google Merchant center, unfortunately. No other way :(

Comment: Ok I see. Thanks for your answer. Need to create feeds then

Comment: Feel free to accept answer if you find it helpful :)